# how to pass application.properties in commandLine for a spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-4

I have a `spring boot` application and I want to pass `application.properties` file in `commandLine` when I `start-up`.

i.e when I run `mvn spring-boot:run --application.properties`

I will have a default application.properties in `src/main/resources`. but that is only for `testing` purposes. In the `production` run, I would like to pass the `property file` in `commandLine.`

I am aware of passing single arguments such as

`mvn spring-boot:run --server.port=9001`.

But I have many such properties and would prefer to pass a property file if that is possible.

Answer (score 30):

You can do that with `spring.config.location` property:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.config.location=your.properties
```

Answer (score 7):

In case if anyone finds it useful as it was for me. If you want to pass in individual application properties as parameters when using the maven spring boot run command you can use the argument spring-boot.run.jvmArguments.

Eg:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments='
-Dspring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb 
-Dspring.datasource.username=admin 
-Dspring.datasource.password=admin'
```

With the above command I am setting (overriding) the following properties which were in the application.properties file.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=admin
```

Comment: Can the above apply to running a jar too ?

Answer (score 5):

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--spring.config.location=classpath:/application-local.properties
```