# Springboot war project with tomcat and external application properties?

Tags: java, tomcat

How can we provide an external application.properties, datasource.properties file with war project that runs on external tomcat? Is there any way to provide these files path as vm arguments in tomcat configuration. Also is it possible to get the values from these files as @Value annotation if use the above configuration?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31819300/how-to-pass-application-properties-in-commandline-for-a-spring-boot-application    You can check this link

Answer (score 0):

Have a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`

```
 <bean name="propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer" class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="location" value="file:${conf.dir}/app.properties" />
</bean>
```

where `conf.dir` you can pass it through JVM arguments like -Dconf.dir=yourconfigFilePath

and use like the following

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="${dataSource.driverClassName}" />
<property name="url" value="${dataSource.url}" />
...
```

File app.properties

```
dataSource.driverClassName=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
dataSource.url=jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/dbpath
```